# two or more for loops time complexity

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

If we assume the statements inside of a for loop is O(1).

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sequence of statements
}
```

Then the above time complexity should be o(n)
another example is:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
        sequence of statements
    }
}
```

the above time complexity should be o(n^2)

It seems like one for loop symbolize n times
However, I've seen some discussion said that it's not simply like this
Sometimes there are 2 for loops but it doesn't mean the time complexity must be o(n^2)

Can somebody give me an example of two or more for loops with only O(n) time complexity (with explanation will be much better)???

Comment: First one isn't o(n) but O(N).

Comment: @don't talk just code
You mentioned some unrelated points to my questions but thanks I've edited them. still don't get the answer

Comment: Your complexities aren't edited, are still all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs when either the outer or inner loop is bounded by a fixed limit (constant value) on iterations. It happens a lot in many problems, like bit manipulation. An example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int x = ...;      //some constant time operations to determine int x
    for (int j = 0; x != 0; j++) {
        x >>>= 1;
    }
}
```

The inner loop is limited by the number of bits for int. For Java, it is 32, so the inner loop is strictly limited by 32 iterations and is constant time. The complexity is linear time or O(n).

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question. The OP's inner loop is bounded by N.  (Also note, I think you mean "fixed time" to determine x, not "linear time". For the latter, the complexity would be O(n*m))

Comment: Yeah! You are right, it is constant or fixed time. Thanks!

Comment: @danh this answer answers OP's real question.  I was on a tangent about the complexity of their initial example, but the question is how to have nested loops with an overal time complexity of O(n).

Comment: @GuyGastineau, agreed. I paid too much attention to the OP code and not enough to the English.  After the minor edit, this is a good answer (to the current question).

Comment: @GuyGastineau Would be even better if both inner and outer loop would (overall) take O(N).

Answer (score 2):

Loops can have fixed time if the bounds are fixed. So for these nested loops, where `k` is a constant:

```
// k is a constant
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<k; j++) {
  }
}

// or this
for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
  }
}
```

Are both `O(kN)` ~= `O(N)`

The *code* in the post has a time complexity of:

[image]

Given this is a second order polynomial, `(N^2 - N)/2`, you correctly assessed the asymptotic time complexity of your example as `O(N^2)`.

Comment: `O(N*(N-1)/2)` and `O(N^2)` are the same.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have formal CS. I have just learned from work and the internet.  How are they the same?   8^2 is 64 but 8(8-1)/2 is 28.

Comment: @bereal Okay, I think I figured out why you said that.  I was thinking of the time complexity function.  The real time complexity, but big O notation is actually talking about it asymptotically.  I will edit my answer for clarity.  I get that the line over inputs will be closer to quadratic than nlogn, but it will always just less than half the quadratic value.  Am I essentially supposed to make a derivative of the time complexity function until I have a sufficiently reduced term for asymptotic time complexity?

Comment: In short, big O shows how fast the algorithm time grows as the input size grows. When dealing with polynomial algorithms, it's enough to consider the polynomial's degree, e.g. `a*n^2 + b*n + c = O(n^2)`.

Comment: @bereal thank you for the explanation.  I am happy to realize I was confusing the real function for the time complexity of an algo with Big O.  I can not confuse these things moving forward :)  If you have a moment, what do you think about the savings we get compared to a real time complexity of f(n) = n^n as n grows to large numbers?  I suppose as n grows toward infinity it stops mattering very much, but I can't help but think about real cases that will run on a computer.  Saving 500,000,000 iterations when n is 1,000,000 seems significant to me intuitively.

Comment: @GuyGastineau, For the ease of future readers, how about editing this answer to its essence.  You've correctly produced an expression for the number of iterations (not the complexity) of the loops, and you've correctly realized that it is a 2nd order polynomial. I think the answer can conclude in about 3 sentences that the complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: @danh I appreciate you edit.  I thought about fixing my pathological example to make more sense (like you did), but what happened to the equation image? It is now replaced by the description I gave for it when uploading.

Comment: @GuyGastineau - my bad. Fixed.